# How can I execute remotely an always running windows console app (.exe) using TFS release tasks in my pipeline?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfsbuild

there is an app "C:\App.Exe" with this spec.

- it is a .Net Windows Console application.
- the app has no user input and any argument.
- it uses "Console.Read();" line in order prevent leaving the app.
- It doesn't possible to rewrite the app in form of a Windows Service because some reason but it's possible to change the code.
- It is not possible to login remote desktop and the app manually,it must be run remotely.

**and I want deploy and run the app within a step task in TFS release pipeline.** I'm using this tools:

- TFS 2018 Update 3 (VSTS)
- Our servers running windows server 2012 R2
- on-premise Windows x64 agent, version 2.136.1

In the previous version of TFS I was able to run the program using this command as I wish.

```
Start "C:\App.exe"
```

but in new version this script doesn't work any more and the task will be killed immediately.

I also tried this command without any result.

```
C:\App.exe /// Causes this exception--> Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.
```

and this one:

```
Start-Process "C:\App.exe" ///Run successfully but the task will be killed immediately.
```

I also replaced the Console.Read(); line in the codes with an  always true While() loop but it causes timeout.

How can I run remotely this app without killing and timeout,within TFS build/release task?

Comment: Do you want the App.exe will keep running after the build finished or only during the build?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk
I want the App.exe will keep running on remote target machine after that the release (not build) tasks finished. Actually App.exe is artifact and should be deployed and run on target machine.

Comment: Try this: Start-Process -wait "C:\App.exe"

Comment: @Fairoz I've tried this but this command causes timeout error

Comment: indeed I need something like this "Start-Process C:\App.exe" without killing the process. but when I run this command in TFS tasks, it run successfuly but killed immediately